# Prevent repetitive results in Select statement

Tags: c#, linq, select, linq-to-entities

I have some beds that are in `Room`,I want to select all `Room`s of my `myBeds` so I used this LINQ statement:

```
IEnumerable<Room> rooms= myBeds.Select(b=>b.Room);
```

but in result there are repetitive `Room`s because some rooms may have more than one bed.How can I prevent repetitive `Room`s?

Comment: Any info on `Room` so that we can have custom quality comparer?

Comment: @KingKing your answer was great ,no more thing needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<Room> rooms= myBeds.Select(b=>b.Room).Distinct();
```

Suppose you have `RoomID` for your `Room`, using `GroupBy` is also OK:

```
IEnumerable<Room> rooms= myBeds.Select(b=>b.Room)
                               .GroupBy(b=>b.RoomID)
                               .Select(g=>g.First());
```